# Find all other cells with same adjacent element

Tags: excel-formula

I have an excel spreadhseet with the following columns

- A: City
- B: State
- C: Other cities that are in the same state as column A

For example, the result may look like this:

```
    City             State                Other cities in State
    --------------------------------------------------------------
    Philadelphia     Pennsylvania        Pitsburgh
    Pitsburgh        Pennsylvania        Philadelphia
    San Diego        California          Palo Alto, Mountain View, LA, San Jose, Houston
    Palo Alto        California          San Jose, Mountain View, San Diego
    Mountain View    California          San Jose, LA, Palo Alto, San Diego
    LA               California          San Jose, Mountain View, Palo Alto, San Diego
    San Jose         California          LA, Mountain View, Palo Alto, San Diego
    Austin           Texas               Houston, Dallas
    Houston          Texas               Austin, Dallas
    Dallas           Texas               Dallas, Houston
```

What formula could I use to generate the 'other cities in state' column?

Comment: Is this a formula only or can VBA be used question? Will the states always be grouped together or will they be mixed up sometimes?

Comment: What excel are you using.

Comment: States may sometimes be mixed up, the won't always be grouped together - and VBA can be used. 

I'm using Excel 2011 for Mac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ragged edge string concatenation is difficult using Excel worksheet functions; even with the new Excel 2016/Office 365/Excel Online [CONCAT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CONCAT-function-9b1a9a3f-94ff-41af-9736-694cbd6b4ca2) and [TEXTJOIN](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TEXTJOIN-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c) functions¹.

A well written UDF² can easily overcome the limitations.

**[Module1 code sheet](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/100009401/Find%20all%20other%20cells%20with%20same%20adjacent%20element.xlsb)**

```
Option Explicit

Function CITYJOIN(rst As Range, sst As String, rct As Range, _
                  Optional sct As String = "", _
                  Optional bIncludeSelf As Boolean = False, _
                  Optional delim As String = ", ")
    Dim r As Long
    Static dict As Object
    If dict Is Nothing Then
        Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        dict.compareMode = vbTextCompare
    End If

    dict.RemoveAll
    'truncate any full column references to the .UsedRange
    Set rst = Intersect(rst, rst.Parent.UsedRange)
    'set the cities to the same size as the states
    Set rct = rct.Resize(rst.Rows.Count, rst.Columns.Count)

    'loop through the cells to create unique dictionary keys
    For r = 1 To rst.Cells.Count
        If LCase(rst(r).Value2) = LCase(sst) Then
            dict.Item(StrConv(rct(r).Value2, vbProperCase)) = vbNullString
        End If
    Next r

    'get rid of 'self-city'
    If Not bIncludeSelf Then
        dict.Remove sct
    End If

    'return a delimited string
    CITYJOIN = Join(dict.keys, delim)

End Function
```

[image: cityjoin]

The optional city (e.g. `sct` ) is only optional if you choose to include the city on the same row. By default the city on the same row is excluded and must be supplied as a parameter in order to remove it.

The **static** dict object means that you will only create the Scripting.Dictionary object once. The same object is used for subsequent calls to the function. This is particularly useful when filling down a long column with a formula containing this UDF.

---

¹ [excel-2016](/questions/tagged/excel-2016) <sub>See [What's new in Excel 2016 for Windows](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/What-s-new-in-Excel-2016-for-Windows-5fdb9208-ff33-45b6-9e08-1f5cdb3a6c73) for more information.</sub>

² <sub>A User Defined Function (aka UDF) is placed into a standard module code sheet. Tap <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> and when the VBE opens, immediately use the pull-down menus to **Insert ► Module** (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>,<kbd>M</kbd>). Paste the function code into the new module code sheet titled something like *Book1 - Module1 (Code)*. Tap <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to return to your worksheet(s).</sub>

Comment: btw, the **La** for **LA** is more a result of your data, not the UDF code. I've included the [StrConv function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264628.aspx) with a cast to **vbProperCase**. If abbreviations are to be used in the data, remove that part of the code. Alternately, use **Los Angeles** as a city.

Comment: managed to get this working perfectly - thanks for your help!