# Proper syntax for calling a particular UDF

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions

This has reference to SO question  [Find all other cells with same adjacent element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36668358/find-all-other-cells-with-same-adjacent-element)  and data reproduced below to avoid cross reference.

I have an excel spreadsheet with the following columns
•   A: City
•   B: State
•   C: Other cities that are in the same state as column A
For example, the result may look like this:

| City | State | Other cities in State |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Philadelphia | Pennsylvania | Pitsburgh |
| Pitsburgh | Pennsylvania | Philadelphia |
| San Diego | California | Palo Alto, Mountain View, LA, San Jose, Houston |
| Palo Alto | California | San Jose, Mountain View, San Diego |
| Mountain View | California | San Jose, LA, Palo Alto, San Diego |
| LA | California | San Jose, Mountain View, Palo Alto, San Diego |
| San Jose | California | LA, Mountain View, Palo Alto, San Diego |
| Austin | Texas | Houston, Dallas |
| Houston | Texas | Austin, Dallas |
| Dallas | Texas | Dallas, Houston |

It was answered by user4039065  who advised  to use an UDF and the code is as follows.

```
Option Explicit

Function CITYJOIN(rst As Range, sst As String, rct As Range, _
                  Optional sct As String = "", _
                  Optional bIncludeSelf As Boolean = False, _
                  Optional delim As String = ", ")
    Dim r As Long
    Static dict As Object
    If dict Is Nothing Then
        Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        dict.compareMode = vbTextCompare
    End If

    dict.RemoveAll
    'truncate any full column references to the .UsedRange
    Set rst = Intersect(rst, rst.Parent.UsedRange)
    'set the cities to the same size as the states
    Set rct = rct.Resize(rst.Rows.Count, rst.Columns.Count)

    'loop through the cells to create unique dictionary keys
    For r = 1 To rst.Cells.Count
        If LCase(rst(r).Value2) = LCase(sst) Then
            dict.Item(StrConv(rct(r).Value2, vbProperCase)) = vbNullString
        End If
    Next r

    'get rid of 'self-city'
    If Not bIncludeSelf Then
        dict.Remove sct
    End If

    'return a delimited string
    CITYJOIN = Join(dict.keys, delim)

End Function
```

It gives correct answer when  used in worksheet as per following formula.

```
   =CITYJOIN(B:B,B2,A:A,A2)
```

My level in VBA is elementary and I want to understand the Function code fully by stepping through the code using `F8` key. With this in view I coded the following Test sub.

```
Sub test()
Call CITYJOIN("B: B", B2, "A: A", A2)
'CITYJOIN B: B , B2, A: A , A2
End Sub
```

I am getting an error at the following line in Function code stating compiler error.

```
 CITYJOIN = Join(dict.keys, delim)
```

Can someone help me and provide proper code of test sub explaining the mistake in the above code of test sub.
Thanks

Comment: Try `Debug.Print CITYJOIN(Range("B:B"), Range("B2").Value, Range("A:A"), Range("A2").Value)` which is corresponding to `=CITYJOIN(B:B,B2,A:A,A2)`. Your function `CITYJOIN` is waiting for the following parameter types (`Range`, `String`, `Range`, `String`) but in `CITYJOIN("B: B", B2, "A: A", A2)` your `"B: B"` is a `String` and `B2` is a `Variable` that is empty (this should actually be triggered by `Option Explicit`).

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Can you help me in providing one line code of calling routine. With my effort I am getting stack overflow  error on line Debug.Print CITYJOIN(Range("B:B"), Range("B2").Value, Range("A:A"), Range("A2").Value)

Comment: @skkakkar: What is the line where you see stack overflow?

Comment: @skkakkar I tested with a new sheet and the data in your question. The output was `Pitsburgh` no errors. If you get errors please [edit] your question show exactly what you did and in which line you got which error message with which data used as input. • Make sure the sheet with data is the active sheet or reference the sheet for every `Range` object in `Debug.Print CITYJOIN(Range("B:B"), Range("B2").Value, Range("A:A"), Range("A2").Value)`.

Comment: The way you try testing is wrong. You should use, in fact It would not be clear in a comment. I will place an answer. Not necessarily to mark it as accepted, even if it does what you want...

Comment: @PEH  In a Function routine I understand F8 stepping is not possible.  With which routine I should call the function. As already mentioned Function code is perfectly OK . What I do not know well is how to test this code and what that routine should be. With which code line you enter the function is important for me as my level of VBA is quite basic. Thanks for your interest and I have learnt a lot from you. Please help me as at my age of 77 years, I do need handholding.

Comment: @skkakkar see the answer FaneDuru posted below. In combination with a sheet that holds the data of your question this should output `Pitsburgh` in the immediate window. Start by putting the cursor in the `test` sub and hit `F8`. Then youn can analyze your `CITYJOIN` function. Just keep hitting `F8` to get to the next line of code.

Comment: I don't know where this rumor comes from, you can of course debug a function. Just set a breakpoint. If you want to debug a function that is used as UDF, force Excel to recalc a cell containing the formula.

Comment: @FunThomas You can do that but when an error occurs it just stops executing the UDF and just returns `#VALUE` or something similar, which does not give you a good ability to debug it really. A VBA test procedure is always better to debug it as you get a more detailed error message if there is an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, call the function in this way:

```
Sub test()
  Debug.print  CITYJOIN(Range("B:B"), Range("B2").value, Range("A:A"), Range("A2").value)
End Sub
```

And see the result in Immediate Window (`Ctrl + G` being in VBE (Visual Basic for Applications Editor).